# Using arrayformula to sum if on certain date

Tags: google-sheets, sum, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I want to count up the number of attendees for a certain month based on the number of attendees on a certain date but can't find the formula to not having it to drag down manually. I've found how to do it for one month and manually drag down this formula (which to my own surprise I've managed to figure out).

Can someone please help me figure out how to do this automatically with an arrayformula so there isn't a need to manually drag down.

Here is what I have a.t.m.

[image: link to photo of sheet]

Link to my google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lLhfe1JDQxsMOS1gjWr5whjj7MRgqN4xNqlmoJ3xK9E/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({TEXT(B2:B, "mmmm yyyy"), C2:C}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col2)''", 0))
```

[image]

---

### UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 
 QUERY({TEXT('input 1'!B2:B, "mmmm yyyy"), 'input 1'!C2:C}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col2)''", 0), 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Why is the reason to use `ARRAYFORMULA` in this case? Seems like using `QUERY` alone would work just fine.

Comment: @Raserhin AF is needed because of TEXT(B2:B, "mmmm yyyy")

Comment: Works great but I have formulated my question wrong. I've updated my sheet to what I want to accomplish. I want to have the formula to work with the manually typed month/year. I've tried it with the query but then the issue is that the data is not of the same amount of rows. Hope you can help

Comment: It's crazy how you guys find such solutions. Thank you very much works exactly how I wanted